# dmesg to check a portable disk

Tags: dmesg

Run `dmesg -T` to check a portable disk and the results

```
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=07a8, bcdDevice=10.42
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb 2-1: Product: My Passport 07A8
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 57584E314535335953313736
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:24 2019] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:25 2019] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 07A8 1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:25 2019] scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:29 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:29 2019] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:29 2019] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:29 2019] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:29 2019] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:30 2019] .
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:35 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:35 2019] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:35 2019] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:35 2019] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 31, error -62
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:36 2019] .
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:40 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:40 2019] ready
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:46 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:46 2019] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 32, error -62
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:46 2019] usb usb2-port3: attempt power cycle
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:52 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:58 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:31:58 2019] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 33, error -62
[Fri Aug 30 21:32:03 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:32:09 2019] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[Fri Aug 30 21:32:09 2019] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 34, error -62
[Fri Aug 30 21:32:09 2019] usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[Fri Aug 30 21:34:40 2019] sd 1:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[Fri Aug 30 21:37:40 2019] sd 1:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
```

Is it damaged? possible or not to repair it?

When running `lsblk` or `fdisk -l`, it is not displayed.

Comment: The problem might be on the enclosure/case you're using. Would it be possible for you to remove the hard disk from the case and try another case? Also, try an USB 2.0 port, sometimes it works.

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual text.

Comment: replaced it. @Murphy ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a power problem (because of aborting while spinning up the drive). Sometimes an own-powered USB hub can help.